# Dictionary or fixed-size list for efficient MongoDB storage

Tags: json, database, mongodb, storage, bson

I've read how BSON works as opposed to JSON, but I still couldn't come to a conclusion which of the following is stored more efficiently in MongoDB:

Ex1:

```
[
    { "f1": "smth", "f2": 0.8, "f3": [[1,2],[3,4]], "f4": 0 },
    { "f1": "smth", "f2": 0.8, "f3": [[1,2],[3,4]], "f4": 0 },
    { "f1": "smth", "f2": 0.8, "f3": [[1,2],[3,4]], "f4": 0 }
]
```

Ex2:

```
[
    ["smth", "smth", "smth"],
    [0.8,0.8,0.8],
    [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]],
    [0,0,0]
]
```

Regardless of the duplicate values of course, I fear that because of the repetitive dictionary keys (i.e., "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"), Ex2 would take less storage space, especially when the number of documents in the DB is in millions. I do consider of course that in Ex2, each array at a different index has a meaning that is not directly declared (as in Ex1 - "f1"...).

Comment: Please tell how are you going to query _anything_ in the `Ex2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your application needs to *work*. It doesn't matter how fast it is if it doesn't provide useful functionality. Assuming you are implementing a real project, these usually not just have non-trivial requirements, but also the requirements change over time. Optimizing your data model (which is quite difficult to change regardless of the database used) at the expense of making your application totally inflexible is generally going to end with the failure of the project.

You can shorten field names if you want. Mongoid for example provides this functionality [out of the box](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#field-aliases).

"Fixed-size list" is not a meaningful term with respect to MongoDB. All arrays can be of any size and the size is encoded in the array. MongoDB isn't implemented like a relational database with fixed row size if you use certain types.

As prasad said, your second option is probably going to become unusable in a hurry once you start trying to query it in any meaningful way, but, if you use MongoDB as a write-only data store and your schema is going to be fixed for the life of the project, sure, your data will take up less space on disk and will be faster to insert if you omit field names and use arrays.

On the other hand, if you want an inexpensive bulk data store that is still queryable, try https://docs.mongodb.com/datalake/.